# OpenCV Error in xCode: Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

I am attempting to apply a vignette to a picture but for some reason I get the error

OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels)

```
+(UIImage *)vignetteImage:(UIImage *)image {
Mat inputImage;
UIImageToMat(image, inputImage);

Mat kernelX = getGaussianKernel(inputImage.cols, 50);
Mat kernelY = getGaussianKernel(inputImage.rows, 50);
Mat kernelXTranspose;
transpose(kernelX, kernelXTranspose);
Mat kernel = kernelY * kernelXTranspose;

Mat mask, processedImage;
normalize(kernel, mask, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);
inputImage.convertTo(processedImage, CV_64F);
multiply(mask, processedImage, processedImage);
convertScaleAbs(processedImage, processedImage);

return MatToUIImage(processedImage);
```

}

The line that throws is

> multiply(mask, processedImage, processedImage);

which I don't understand as I am taking the same image and applying the mask to itself. So the arrays should match?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error - I need to convert the image to grayscale first, otherwise the array Mat kernel is a different size than that of the image I want to convert:

```
+(UIImage *)vignetteImage:(UIImage *)image {
Mat inputImage;
UIImageToMat(image, inputImage);

// Transform the cv::Mat color image to grayscale
Mat grayMat;
cvtColor(inputImage, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);

Mat kernelX = getGaussianKernel(grayMat.cols, 50);
Mat kernelY = getGaussianKernel(grayMat.rows, 50);
Mat kernelXTranspose;
transpose(kernelX, kernelXTranspose);
Mat kernel = kernelY * kernelXTranspose;

Mat mask, processedImage;
normalize(kernel, mask, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);
grayMat.convertTo(processedImage, CV_64F);
multiply(mask, processedImage, processedImage);
convertScaleAbs(processedImage, processedImage);

return MatToUIImage(processedImage);
}
```